# Ubuntu ldap doesn't return all users's groups

Tags: ubuntu, directory, ldap

Having a weird issue with one user.
We're using AD and using ldap-auth-client on ubuntu.

RHEL output

```
$ id -a user1
uid=600001(user1) gid=100(users),groups=100(users),60002(group1),60003(group2),60004(group3)
```

Ubuntu output:

```
$ id -a user1
uid=600001(user1) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),60002(group1)
```

Anyone happened to have any similar issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verify first that those are not local groups -- you *can* put LDAP users into local groups. If you are actually seeing two different lists of group memberships from the directory, can you compare the configuration between the two boxes? They could be looking at different parts of the directory tree when searching for groups or using a different scope (onelevel v/s subtree).

I've had Linux/Unix hosts put filters so only *relevant* groups show up too. Something like

```
nss_base_group  ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=gTLD?sub?(&(someattr=MyServerName)(cn=*))
```

Will only display groups that have MyServerName in the someattr attribute. Where

```
nss_base_group  ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=gTLD?sub?(&(cn=*))
```

would show all groups.

Comment: I don't have any filters